# How to create door between two rooms using archimesh?

Tags: archimesh-add-on

I'm trying to connect two rooms created in archimesh with door frame:
[image: start]
but when I'm using auto holes it doesn't work. The only result is dissapearing of door groups:
[image: finish]
I've seen solution: join rooms, but in that case I can't create floor, ceiling, change size of walls and other. How to do that?

Update: I've tried to gave solidify modifier to floors, join rooms (Ctrl+J) and then use Auto Holes, but the result still awful:
[image: update version]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, at thit moment I found only one way to achieve it. If we'll use ONLY ONE room with many walls, we can create auto holes without problems. We just need to combine visible and hidden walls to create additional rooms with complex corners and other architectural things. But in this case you better not to use floor and ceiling option, most likely you'll receive only broken floor and ceiling (I suppose, floor is creating for all walls, visible and hidden). I hope there is a better answer to my question, so I will glad to see more opinions.[image: normal door]

Answer (score 1):

The BagaPie addon (free) on Gumroad can create booleans that will cut away at a mesh. If you use it and create a square in the doorway, it will make a hole in the mesh. Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't quite understand: is there any difference between boolean modifier and boolean from BagaPie? I mean, of course I can use boolean to create a square in room, but maybe there is another way? I already have that boolean (doorframe), the problem is that boolean doesn't affect on two meshes.

Comment: Okay. I didn't quite understand your problem. To my knowledge booleans can only affect one object at a time, and so you'd have to join the rooms. Perhaps you could design everything else first, then join the rooms, and then add the boolean?

Comment: I've tried to do that. But when I'm joining rooms, my floor and ceiling are disappearing... sometimes. I hope there is a better way to create normal doors(

Comment: Weird. Have you tried looking at archimesh's documentation?

Comment: Of course. The first thing I've done. I suppose they have only video [documentation](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLQAfj95MdhTJ7zifNb5ab-n-TI0GmKwWQ) and I didn't find any mentions about two rooms connections.

Comment: You could try to convert them to meshes before joining them.

Comment: They are already meshes when you create them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135475/discussion-between-blendermaster15-and-).